# Select the posts with OR operator in the same meta_key AND operator for differemt meta_key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have stucked with a mysql query.

I want to select the `posts` having `OR` operator between same `meta_key` then `AND` operator on different meta_key i have tried :-

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, pm.meta_value FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN  `wp_postmeta` pm ON p.ID =pm.post_id where 
((pm.meta_key = 'cost_for_two' AND pm.meta_value IN(".$prices.")) 
AND (pm.meta_key = 'bar_or_no_bar' AND pm.meta_value='".$bars."')  )  LIMIT 0,7
```

Want to select the post who have bars and prices selected.

Answer (score 0):

as you said "**Want to select the post who have bars and prices selected.**"
You can do this by Wordpress query too.

try this code:

```
    $args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'key' => 'cost_for_two',
                    'value' => $prices,
            ),
            array(
                    'key' => 'bar_or_no_bar',
                    'value' => $bars,
            )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 7
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```